# 4-day stopover in Frankfurt, what about my luggage?

Tags: transit, germany, canada, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen travelling to Canada via Frankfurt on August 14th. My next flight is on the 19th. My Canadian visa is a student visa, and I also have a Schengen visa (visiting). 
Will my luggage be available in Frankfurt, and will I have to check in again after 4 days?
If so, will my luggage's weight be a problem? Currently in my ticket, it is 2pc: that means 20kg×2.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  If you're entering Germany you will have to go through customs and then recheck your luggage.  The rules for luggage of the outgoing flight will depend on the airline rules, so airline would be important.

Comment: @Karlson Not sure this is actually related to entering Germany. It would mostly depend on the duration of the layover and how you booked the flights, I think

Answer (score 2):

For a layover under 24 hours, it should be possible to check your luggage through to the US and you could therefore go through the passport check and take a quick trip to the city without collecting your luggage.

However, a 4-day stopover is usually too long for that, even if the whole trip is on one ticket, so you will almost certainly have to collect your luggage in this case. I am not sure if it makes a difference regarding the allowance, you need to check that with the airline.

If your flights are not part of the same booking, the question is moot, you will have to recheck your luggage and abide by the rules of the second airline in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, a, sure, you must check out your luggage when you arrive, and b, you'll have to check it in again 4 days later.

(it's 99.99% unlikely the next airline will allow you to check it in four days early.)

regarding the weight, check carefully with your ongoing airline.